# django-summernote view uploaded image from template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, summernote

I'm trying to view my uploaded images when uploading from summernote.

Here is my static and media for settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_ROOT = "static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/./"
```

This articles.html template displays my static files just fine:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
  {% for post in object_list %}
  <div class="card rounded border-1 border-secondary">
    <div class="card-header bg-dark text-light">
        <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
        <small>Posted: {{ post.date }}</small>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body bg-light">
      <img src={{ post.image.url }} width="300" height="200">
      <p class="card-text">{{ post.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body bg-light">
      <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}" class="card-link">Read more...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I need to embed images in my post_detail.html post.body (|safe just for testing):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="post-entry">
    <h2>{{ post.title  }}</h2>
    <p>{{ post.body|safe }}</p>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

When I try to update the post.body with the images I get:

```
[07/Feb/2019 12:43:24] "GET /admin/blog/post/2/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10150
[07/Feb/2019 12:43:24] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
[07/Feb/2019 12:43:25] "GET /summernote/editor/id_body/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6349
[07/Feb/2019 12:43:27] "GET /static/summernote/lang/summernote-en-US.min.js?_=1549561406677 HTTP/1.1" 200 27
[07/Feb/2019 12:43:38] "POST /summernote/upload_attachment/ HTTP/1.1" 200 179
Not Found: /django-summernote/2019-02-07/c4ad147f-01d0-464f-ab2d-e2ce60d5c62f.jpg
[07/Feb/2019 12:43:38] "GET /django-summernote/2019-02-07/c4ad147f-01d0-464f-ab2d-e2ce60d5c62f.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4071
[07/Feb/2019 12:43:42] "POST /admin/blog/post/2/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[07/Feb/2019 12:43:42] "GET /admin/blog/post/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4758
[07/Feb/2019 12:43:43] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
```

When I check the post_detail.html page there is no image, but works fine when embedded from a link.

I don't want to change my media root or url, to avoid breaking its usage on other parts of the site.

Tried to search for quite a while, but I can't find out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Well then...

Sometimes just trying some more things works better than hours of searching.

Changing my MEDIA_URL to:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/django-summernote/"
```

Solved all my issues, I can upload images to the database and use them for my post thumbnails and in my post body if I want.